# Como comparar duas datas no DatagridView e mudar de cor quando expirar VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, sql-server-2012

Meus codigos

```
Private Sub CadastroDataGridView_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles CadastroDataGridView.CellFormatting
If Me.CadastroDataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn15" Then
    If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dgvdate As Date = CDate(e.Value)
        If dgvdate < CDate(Now) Then
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
            e.FormattingApplied = True
        Else
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
            e.FormattingApplied = True
        End If

    End If
    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Explica melhor, você quer fazer isso no load ou por evento? Coloque o código de como esta populando o datagrid, geralmente eu faço numa rotina a parte depois de popular o grid, ai comparo o dado do objeto que quero popular e formato o grid neste método.

Comment: Quero fazer no Load, logo que o usuario logar automaticamente tem que colorir todas tabelas expiradas. @EzequieldaSilvaDaniel

Comment: De onde vem "Consulta"? @EzequieldaSilvaDaniel

Answer (score 1):

Deve ficar algo do tipo:

```
For Each linha As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView_consulta.Rows
     valor_celula = linha.Cells(2).Value

     If valor_celula = "Aberto" Then
          linha.Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
End If
```

Só substituir ai a comparação por data e colocar em um método sendo chamado no load. A ideia é percorrer as linhas do datagrid, pegar o valor da célula, que é uma coluna fixa e seta o estilo dela.

Comment: Obrigado, vou experimentar e digo algo

Comment: Ezequiel, sou um programador amador, poderia me explicar melhor isso?